# How can I clean a glass top oven that has black areas?

Tags: cleaning, kitchen, glass, appliances

I have scrubbed until it's a smooth surface that feels very similar to the original glass top but the surface is so dark it's nearly black. I can slightly see the original pattern in the dark areas which makes me think it might be salvageable.

If anyone has any ideas I'd be happy to try them.

What I've tried:

- Razor blade
- Aluminum foil ball
- Barkeepers Friend
- Baking Soda with (Peroxide, or water, or vinegar)
- Sulfuric Acid [Strong drain cleaner] (but I did not scrub)

[image: the glass top]

Comment: Try leaving a drop of 100% bleach to see if the color changes. If not, try a drop of acid. Metal and/or carbon are embedded into the glass texture. All surfaces are rough when viewed microscopically. Probably cannot be removed.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I actually forgot to mention that I had tried sulfuric acid. I will try the bleach and see if it makes it at least look better. I will let you know of the outcome.

Comment: I tried acid again, left it on longer and scrubbed, I did not notice a difference. I also tried leaving bleach on it for about 2 hours, still nothing. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Have you tried oven cleaner? Warm the surface first then apply oven cleaner, leave for a little while then use a scrapper to gently scrape the surface. After rinse surface.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure the stain is not on the other side?

If it's on the surface then.

1. Polishing compound - You can use a car rubbing compound with a low grit, they use to put a mirror finish on paintjobs, it wont hurt your surface.
2. 800+ grit sandpaper.  Again, it's used to put a mirror finish on car paint jobs.

   - it's wet sandpaper (it will be black, if it's light colored, it's for wood)
   - Once your've hit it with the 800 you can then start using 1000+ grit and put a mirror                    finish on it.

Comment: Welcome to LH, paul, and thanks for your answer (+1). How long do you think this should take?

Comment: I will give that a try and let you know. Thanks Paul.

Comment: Using either method I would think that 15 minutes of work with a couple of minutes of cleanup should probably do the trick.  If you feel tentative and are testing then add a bit more.  Good luck!

Comment: I tried these a few times now, even combining them both at times. Sadly it did not work. I think it may be permanent but I guess I'm now ready to make my car shine! lol